# move div item on top of div container when being onclicked

Tags: javascript, css

!http://postimg.org/image/ym5xp7ilv/

what i would like to achieve is to move the div item which is clicked on the top of the div container when each item is clicked...the rest of the items(those who are not being clicked) would fill the rest of the div container respectively

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="containing_div">
                <div class="container_div"></div>
                <div class="menu_div">
                    <div class="item_div">Photos</div>
                    <div class="item_div">Video</div>
                    <div class="item_div">Music</div>
                    <div class="item_div">Files</div>
                    <div class="item_div">Contacts</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.containing_div
{
  height: 100%;
}

.container_div
{
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 26px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu_div
{
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
}

.item_div
{
  background: #ddd;
  height: 80px;
  color: #bbb;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 0 2% 2% 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

Comment: manipulate the `z-index` of the div with javascript when it is clicked.

Comment: I assume that you mean the `item_div`?

Comment: exacly...yes..i mean "item_div"

Comment: Ok I'll write an answer with a jsfiddle.....

Comment: please write jsfiddle....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8twbjrkn/ or with the active tab white, as in your pic: http://jsfiddle.net/8twbjrkn/1/

Comment: thanks...i used exacly the same method to resolve my issue...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you desire, you can achieve your target with a little of jQuery, thanks to `prependTo` method.

[Here the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fr646r6a/) and the jQuery function.

```
$('.item_div').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prependTo('.container_div');
});
```

UPDATE:

If you want to simply swap positions, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fr646r6a/1/) a variation.

```
$('.item_div').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prependTo('.menu_div');
});
```

Comment: this doesn't really working..it's just removes the div items from the div container

Comment: In my example, removes them form `.menu-div` and place them into `.container_div`. Did not ask this?

Comment: he may want this: http://jsfiddle.net/8twbjrkn/  to move the div to top of list.  If so, just change '.container_div' to '.menu_div'

Comment: no i did not ask this...exchange the positions of .item_div inside .menu_div when one item div is clicked i want the specific item to move on the top of menu div

Comment: ok i solved the issue..i just used $(this).prependTo(".menu_div")